# Springboot with Keycloak adapter redirecting to login page when authorization fail

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

In history I was able to create API with keycloak adapter and secure all endpoints based on user's role.

Today (year later), I am trying to do the same (nearly copy paste from previous solution) but without success..

I have created a super simple API with spring boot. Defined SecurityConfig like:

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

and also 1 endpoint

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public Test testEndpoint() {
        return new Test();
    }
```

But whenever I try to send a GET on /test (without authorization header), I get redirect response to {{authorization_url}} specified in OpenID configuration (keycloak-spring-boot-starter successfully manages to download this configuration from Keycloak itself). Which I understand that Keycloak wants me to redirect to the login page and log in myself.

This is kind of new. Previously, this did not happen and springboot just simply returned 401 or so...

Is there an option, some settings where can I change this behavior so it doesn't response with redirection ? Instead, just throws an exception?

Comment: Did you configure bearer only option to true?

Comment: oh.. yeah, that did the trick.. I wonder, why I didn't need to use it before. As I am looking to my previous API, I do not have this option on and it is still working.. Please, can you write an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure bearer-only option to true - it will enable "API" mode, so it will return `401 Unauthorized` http responses. You have it in the "web app" mode now, which redirects users to the IDP login (and that's not good behaviour for API calls).

Answer (score 0):

set this on the `application.properties` file:

`keycloak.bearer-only=TRUE`

or `application.yml` file:

```yaml
keycloak:
  bearer-only: true
```